# Strange behaviour of my table on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

On this website http://www.massedeschenaux.org/index.php (yeah, it's old and all in table), everything works fine on Chrome and FF. But on IE11, I see a white separation between two images (the two indications) and my round bottom background doesn't display correctly.

Comment: Check the browser mode. If it's quirks mode or compatibility mode, then the odds are you've found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td width="300" align="left" background="images/background3.gif"
```

Just change `align="right"` for `align="left"`

Comment: Why not use CSS instead? Also, aligning things in tables are bad practice.

Comment: @ZDroid I agree that working with the css is the correct approach but the question was not about whether or not use CSS.

Comment: I know, justa tip for you. :)